# Turn off "Allow Notifications" pop-up in Firefox

Tags: firefox, notifications

When I browse to different websites using Firefox I regularly get a Firefox pop-up asking me to give the website permission to send me notifications.

[image]

I have 3 options here

1. Allow Notifications
2. Not Now
3. Never Allow

It appears that "Never Allow" is only for the specific site - if I go to another site the pop-up will appear again for that site.

I don't use the notification feature and would like the pop-up turned off completely for all sites, but am unsure if this is possible.

In the Firefox options, under Privacy and Security, there is a Permissions section that includes Notifications:

[image]

However choosing "Settings..." here just shows me the sites I have already Allowed or Not Allowed, and doesn't give an option to turn off the pop-up.  The *Pause notifications until Firefox restarts* does not stop these pop-ups from appearing, it just mutes notifications that you have previously allowed.  And clicking "Learn more" tells me about the notifications and how to add them to my own website, but not how to disable them in Firefox.

How can I turn off this pop-up so that I am no longer asked for permission for websites to send notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To permanently disable Push notifications in Firefox:

Go to `about:config` in your browser adresss bar and accept the "Here Be Dragons" warning:[image]

Look for:   `dom.webnotifications.enabled`:[image]

and set it's value to `'false'`.  To change the value you can either double click it or right click and select "Toggle"

Restart firefox and you're sorted :)

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1141800

This will completely disable push notifications and Firefox won't ask your permission again.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely disable notification queries in the following manner:

1. Within a new Firefox tab, type `about:config` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Click the ensuing button that says `I accept the risk!`
3. In the `Search` field at the top, type **dom.webnotifications.enabled**
4. Double-click on the result under `Preference Name` to change the value to **false**
5. Close the Firefox browser and reopen it, now without notification queries

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: @marcus perhaps you could elaborate a bit beyond simply saying *"Doesn't work..."*.  What version of Firefox are you using?  What is your host OS?  I am using this modification within the 64-bit version of Firefox 58.0.2 on a Windows 10 Version 1709 machine, and I **never** see the `Allow Notifications` pop-up.

Comment: 58.0.2  on Ubuntu 16.04. To make it work dom.push.enabled needs to be false...

Comment: @marcus It's possible that Firefox version works a bit differently for Linux zealots.  If that's the case, that sounds like a great opportunity for you to post *another* good answer!